# Web Application for logging customers tasks/service

Tags: productivity, logs, crm

I'm an outsourcing IT and I would like somehow to keep an online logbook for my clients. For example a call would be that the server of the X company is down. I would like after the job is done to keep a log of the incident and what I have done to fix the issue. So next time the same or similar problem comes up to have an overview. This can also determine if a hardware is unreliable etc.

In addition, id its possible to be able to store some files (like cisco config files) for each customer.

This app will be managed by myself only, so no team features are required. I am currently using my owncloud server creating text documents. In the beginning was ok but, now I have a bunch of text files and is very time consuming when I need to look up for something specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to check out [Odoo as a maintenance software](https://www.odoo.com/page/tpm-maintenance-software). If that doesn't do exactly what you're looking for, you can always add different components too. It's also open source and free to use on your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an issue tracker. Some options:

Free:

1. [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org)
2. [Fossil](https://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Commercial:

1. [FreshService](https://freshservice.com/itil-incident-management-tool)
2. [Atlassian JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)